# Automapper ConfigurationExpression Condition

Tags: automapper

Quick question - whats the difference in the following?

This one works:

```cs
CreateMap<OrderResult, OrderViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.SoldTo, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.ShipTo, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.ShowPlaceOrder, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Messages.Count == 0));
```

I would expect this one to do pretty much the same thing except "Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();" fails on this one saying that "ShowPlaceOrder" is not mapped.

```cs
CreateMap<OrderResult, OrderViewModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.SoldTo, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.ShipTo, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ForMember(x => x.ShowPlaceOrder, opt => opt.Condition(c => c.Messages.Count == 0));
```

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need to provide a source for `ShowPlaceOrder` in case the condition is true.  The "Condition" method takes a predicate to decide if the mapping should be done.  I think your first example is more clear.

Comment: Could you provide of opt.Condition() and opt.MapFrom() used together please?

Comment: I don't think you would ever do that.  If you have some boolean condition, you would provide as part of the MapFrom (probably using C#'s ?: operator).

Comment: @shatl -- I misunderstood your question.  If you need both MapFrom and Condition, you just create two ForMember calls to the same destination -- one with ForMember and one with Condition.  Order doesn't matter.

Comment: I was thinking of right approach to do following conditional mapping `src.value = (dest.Nested != null) ? dest.Nested.Value : 0)`

Thanks